# Firefox: how to block link

Tags: firefox, block

I'm using **Firefox** as a web browser so I want block some links where I can doing it from **Firefox** ? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox as your Internet browser and want to block websites from being viewed, you will find that Firefox as a standalone web browser does not have a website blocking feature. However, Firefox supports the use of third-party add-on programs, and BlockSite is a third-party Firefox add-on that you can use to make a list of websites that you want blocked in your browser [Click to Install](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/).